# Group data table and apply cut function to columns by reference

Tags: r, data.table

Using the data provide below, I would like to group my data table by Date and, by column reference (`colstoCut`), apply the cut function in my code.  I can achieve this using `dplyr` but my actual data is quite large and it's too slow. I've made several attempts based on approaches I've found on SO and elsewhere but nothing I've found so far seems to work.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

cutme <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
18993, 18994, 18994, 18994, 18994, 18994, 18995, 18995, 18995, 
18995, 18995, 18996, 18996, 18996, 18996, 18996, 18997, 18997, 
18997, 18997, 18997), class = "Date"), val1 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
    val2 = c(306, 291, 306, 300, 306, 295, 299, 291, 302, 298, 
    301, 300, 291, 301, 297, 290, 294, 298, 293, 294, 310, 305, 
    293, 322, 299), val3 = c(278.115915402059, 275.206632766366, 
    277.843871977486, 274.375934310537, 271.976342200702, 314.694861131995, 
    322.55015422103, 312.56565930567, 321.31779178896, 310.742656596237, 
    294.839125866978, 305.946938215211, 317.090018318496, 319.386088532157, 
    312.323793703966, 309.29514039576, 313.96520162878, 317.360306029457, 
    310.212544203034, 320.263145398593, 310.432980834677, 296.638028917156, 
    294.622602772748, 305.922855022984, 308.30568677617)), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), groups = structure(list(`Date,` = structure(c(18993, 18994, 
18995, 18996, 18997), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20, 21:25), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

# cut these columns [transforms them to bins (factors)]
colstoCut <- colnames(cutme)[-1]

# approach using dplyr (works but too slow on real data)
cutme <- cutme %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Date) %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at(all_of(colstoCut), ~cut(x = ., breaks = unique(quantile(x = ., probs = seq(0,1,0.025))), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup(.)

## several attempts using data.table ##

# no error thrown but columns are not actually cut
cutme[, (colstoCut) := Map(function(x) cut(x = ., breaks = seq(0,1,0.0025), include.lowest = TRUE)), by = Date]

# Error in cut.default(x = ., breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.0025), include.lowest = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
cutme[, (colstoCut) := lapply(.SD, cut(x = ., breaks = seq(0,1,0.0025), include.lowest = TRUE)), by = Date, .SDcols = colstoCut]

# Error in cut.default(x = ., breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.0025), include.lowest = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
in_cols <- colstoCut
out_cols <- paste0(in_cols,"fact")
cutme[, (out_cols) := lapply(.SD, cut(x = ., breaks = seq(0,1,0.0025), include.lowest = TRUE)), by = Date, .SDcols = in_cols]

# Error in cut.default(x = ., breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.0025), include.lowest = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
cutme[, (colstoCut) := lapply(colstoCut, function(x) cut(x = ., breaks = seq(0,1,0.0025), include.lowest = TRUE)), by = Date]

# Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : recursive indexing failed at level 2
cutme[, (colstoCut) := lapply(.SD, cut(x = cutme[[colstoCut]], breaks = seq(0,1,0.0025), include.lowest = TRUE)), by = Date]
```

Comment: the `x = .` doesn't make any sense.  You need a lambda expression i..e `lapply(.SD, function(.) cut(x = ., ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given sample dataset with 1 grouping column and 3 value columns to be transformed, the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) equivalent of OP's [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) code simply is

```
library(data.table)
mycut <- \(x) cut(x, unique(quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.025))), include.lowest = TRUE)
cutme <- setDT(cutme)[, lapply(.SD, mycut), .SDcols = colstoCut, by = Date]
cutme
```

> ```
>           Date    val1        val2            val3
>         <Date>  <fctr>      <fctr>          <fctr>
>  1: 2022-01-01 (1.9,2] (305.4,306] (278.09,278.12]
>  2: 2022-01-01 [1,1.1] [291,291.9] (275.12,275.21]
>  3: 2022-01-01 [1,1.1] (305.4,306] (277.58,277.84]
>  4: 2022-01-01 [1,1.1] (299.1,300] (274.14,274.38]
>  5: 2022-01-01 (1.9,2] (305.4,306] [271.98,272.22]
>  6: 2022-01-02 [0,0.1] (294.6,295]   (314.5,314.7]
>  7: 2022-01-02 [0,0.1] (298.9,299]   (322.4,322.6]
>  8: 2022-01-02 (0.9,1] [291,291.4]   (312.4,312.6]
>  9: 2022-01-02 [0,0.1] (301.7,302]   (320.7,321.3]
> 10: 2022-01-02 [0,0.1] (297.7,298]   [310.7,310.9]
> 11: 2022-01-03 [0,0.1] (300.9,301]   [294.8,295.9]
> 12: 2022-01-03 (0.9,1] (299.7,300]   (304.8,305.9]
> 13: 2022-01-03 (0.9,1] [291,291.6]   (316.6,317.1]
> 14: 2022-01-03 (1.9,2] (300.9,301]   (319.2,319.4]
> 15: 2022-01-03 (0.9,1] (296.4,297]   (311.7,312.3]
> 16: 2022-01-04 (0.9,1] [290,290.3]  [309.3,309.39]
> 17: 2022-01-04 (1.9,2] (293.9,294] (313.59,313.97]
> 18: 2022-01-04 (0.9,1] (297.6,298] (317.02,317.36]
> 19: 2022-01-04 [0,0.1] (292.7,293] (310.12,310.21]
> 20: 2022-01-04 [0,0.1] (293.9,294] (319.97,320.26]
> 21: 2022-01-05 (0.9,1] (309.5,310]   (310.2,310.4]
> 22: 2022-01-05 (0.9,1] (304.4,305]   (296.4,296.6]
> 23: 2022-01-05 [0,0.1] [293,293.6]   [294.6,294.8]
> 24: 2022-01-05 [0,0.1] (320.8,322]     (305,305.9]
> 25: 2022-01-05 (0.9,1] (298.4,299]   (308.1,308.3]
>           Date    val1        val2            val3
> ```

Comment: thanks for providing an answer that cuts the existing columns directly without needing to select / unselect. I haven't seen the use of `\(x)` before. Mind explaining what that does and when it should be used?

Comment: `\(x)` is a shortcut for `function(x)` which was introduced recently with R version 4.1.0

Comment: @On_an_island, you mentioned performance issues with your code. Is the [tag:data.table]  code faster? I had planned to do some benchmarks on my own before posting the answer but I hadn't got the time to do so.

Comment: yes, the data.table code is significantly faster on my real data that contains anywhere from 5-10 million rows and over 300 columns that need to be cut and binned in this manner.  the data.table approach is amazing! thank you for providing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from akrun the following worked for me:

```
in_cols <- colstoCut
out_cols <- paste0(in_cols,"_fact")
cutme[, (out_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(.) cut(x = ., breaks = unique(quantile(x = ., probs = seq(0,1,0.025))), include.lowest = TRUE)), by = Date, .SDcols = (in_cols) ]
cutme <- cutme %>%
  dplyr::select(Date, all_of(out_cols)
colnames(cutme) <- gsub("_fact","",colnames(cutme))
```

Because I wasn't able to directly transform the numeric columns into factor columns like I can with `dplyr::mutate_at(vars(colstoCut), ~cut(...))` I removed the original (uncut) columns from the data table and selected the new cut columns / renamed using `gsub`.

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this without resorting to selecting / renaming columns but it works for me.  I'm happy to accept a better answer once and if it's posted.